# Combinaciones python

Tags: python

tengo que hacer un algorimo que muestre todas las combinaciones r de n elementos, yo hice esto usando itertools:

```
from itertools import combinations
def Generar_Combinaciones(n,r):
    if n>r:
       x=list(range(1,n+1))
       print x
       for x in combinations(x,r):
           print x
    else:
       print 'R no puede ser mayor a N'
Generar_Combinaciones(10,2)
```

pero quiero hacerlo sin usar itertools, alguien me podria ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Sin modificar mucho tu código, ¿es algo así lo que buscarías?

```
def Generar_Combinaciones(n, r):
    if n > r:
        lista = list(range(1, n + 1))
        print(lista)
        for n, element in enumerate(lista):
            for subElement in lista[n + 1:]:
                print((element, subElement))
    else:
        print('R no puede ser mayor a N')
```

Simplificándolo un poquito podría ser así:

```
def Generar_Combinaciones2(n, r):
    if n > r:
        for x in range(1, n + 1):
            for y in range(x + 1, n + 1):
                print((x, y))
    else:
        print('R no puede ser mayor a N')
```

En este caso `range(1, n + 1)` crearía un objeto tipo `range` que empieza en 1 y acaba en 10.
En el siguiente bucle `range(x + 1, n + 1)` crearía un objeto tipo `range` que empieza en x+1 y acaba en 10. Es decir:

```
Valor x  |  Valor range
1  |  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
2  |  3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
3  |  4 5 6 7 8 9 10
4  |  5 6 7 8 9 10
...  |  ...
```

Luego solo hay que combinarlos.